# How to add a node to the Ethereum Network Status page?

Tags: nodes, network, statistics, monitoring

How to add a node to the [Ethereum Network Status](https://ethstats.net/) page?

[image: Network Status]

Does that not happen automatically? What is required to get listed on that page?

Comment: but i see a node named `5chdn-miner-x390` is it yours ?

Comment: Yes, it's one of my miners. It's a _canonical question_ to improve the content and quality of this site. I know the answer and will post it if nobody else knows.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is [here on the Ethereum wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Network-Status). It's too long to quote here. One thing to note is that when you want the value of the `WS_SECRET` you click on the link and it opens up Skype (if you have it installed and associated with the skype: protocol) and the value you want is in the name of the channel - you don't need to ask anyone on Skype.

Another tip is that if you drop off the page, it may be because the server's been rebooted, in which case you need to restart the stats process as described on the wiki page.

Comment: Nothing is too long to be quoted here. Also don't quote but rather try to explain.

Comment: @q9f please what's the answer?