# How can I verify that the network sees my node?

Tags: network, raspberry-pi

I've set up an Ethereum node on a spare Raspberry Pi 2 with a 64GB memory card. I used the excellent instructions found on [github](https://github.com/EthEmbedded/Raspi-Eth-Install). The blockchain has synced. I have a few questions:

- How can I verify that the network sees my node?
- Do I need to configure any port forwarding?
- Anything else that should be on my radar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Star the client `geth` or `eth` as seen on [step 9](https://github.com/EthEmbedded/Raspi-Eth-Install#installation-method), upon doing this   your node will get start to sync if it not already synced.

You can see your node [ethernodes.org](https://www.ethernodes.org).

Also there is [ethstats.net](https://ethstats.net) see [How to add a node to the Ethereum Network Status page?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1282/how-to-add-a-node-to-the-ethereum-network-status-page)

[image]